# Flex: Comparing two identical dictionaries with ObjectUtil fails?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, dictionary, mxml

I want to compare two dictionaries using ObjectUtil.compare(). When the dictionaries are identical (two different instances, but with identical contents), the comparison fails with a strange exception:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "some_key" to QName.
```

Here's some code to make it clearer.

Main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<local:MainTest xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:local="*"/>
```

MainTest.as

```
package {
  import spark.components.Application;
  import flash.utils.Dictionary;
  import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

  public class MainTest extends Application {
    public function MainTest() {
      super();
      trace(ObjectUtil.compare(getMyDictionary(), getMyDictionary()));
    }

    private function getMyDictionary() : Dictionary {
      var myDictionary : Dictionary = new Dictionary();
      myDictionary["oranges"] = "orange";
      myDictionary["kiwis"] = "green";
      return myDictionary;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the constructor calls `ObjectUtil.compare` with two dictionaries. The `getMyDictionary()` method obviously returns new, identical dictionaries every time (different instances, of course, but they're identical). When the code gets to `ObjectUtil.compare()`, the debugger prints the following error:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "oranges" to QName.
```

Why would it want to compare the "oranges" key with a QName?

**Note:** if I call `ObjectUtil.compare` giving the same instance as arguments, it works properly. I mean that if I save the return value of `getMyDictionary()` into a variable `myDict` and call `ObjectUtil.compare(myDict, myDict)`, then the error won't appear, and the comparison will pass.

Can anyone shed some light? Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Flex sdk.
Use `Object` instead of `Dictionary` if you're not going to use any key types except `String`.

```
private function getMyDictionary() : Object {
      var myDictionary : Object = new Object();
      myDictionary["oranges"] = "orange";
      myDictionary["kiwis"] = "green";
      return myDictionary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Fun fact: I've found some version of this class [here](http://svn.stefanix.net/filedetails.php?repname=actionscript&path=%2Fflex%2Fframeworks%2Fprojects%2Fframework%2Fsrc%2Fmx%2Futils%2FObjectUtil.as) and guess what: this version doesn't have the bug! Also, it is 1426 days old.

Answer (score 0):

when gone through the docs i found this, may be this is helpful

> mx.utils.ObjectUtil.compare(a:Object, b:Object, depth:int=-1):int
>
> Compares the **Objects and returns an integer value** indicating if the
> first item is less than greater than or equal to the second item. This
> method will recursively compare properties on nested objects and will
> return as soon as a non-zero result is found. By default this method
> will recurse to the deepest level of any property. To change the depth
> for comparison specify a non-negative value for the depth parameter.
> Parameters: a Object. b Object. depth Indicates how many levels should
> be recursed when performing the comparison. Set this value to 0 for a
> shallow comparison of only the primitive representation of each
> property.
>
> For example:

```
   var a:Object = {name:"Bob", info:[1,2,3]};
   var b:Object = {name:"Alice", info:[5,6,7]};
   var c:int = ObjectUtil.compare(a, b, 0);
```

> In the above example the complex properties of a and b will be
> flattened by a call to toString() when doing the comparison. In this
> case the info property will be turned into a string when performing
> the comparison.
>
> Returns:
>
> Return 0 if a and b are null, NaN, or equal.   Return 1 if a is null
> or greater than b.   Return -1 if b is null or greater than a.
>
> Language Version: 3.0
>
> Player Version:Flash 9, AIR 1.1
>
> Product Version:Flex 3